# Add entry to form within a form via button in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

To illustrate what I am trying to do I will use an example:

I have a create recipe form and within this form I intend to have some character fields and two other forms:
1. A steps form
2. An ingredients form

for each of these forms I want to have a button that allows you to add another step or another ingredient.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFxNv.jpg) of what I have so far to give you an idea.

Then I need to compact all of the fields and forms into the single create_recipe form.

Has anyone tried to do something like this before?

I can attach some of the code I have if that would be helpful.

Thanks,

katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it up as follows:

1. Create a recipe form
2. Create a steps form and based on that a steps formset
3. Create a ingredient form and based on that a ingredient formset
4. Add the recipe form, steps formset and ingredient formset to your template.
5. Build the handling of those 3 in your underlying view
6. Make your formsets dynamic, i.e. add and delete buttons, with http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/

This link might be very helpful for some implementation details: http://haineault.com/blog/155/

Comment: this looks like a great start to my problem. I am going away this weekend and will pick it back up on monday. thanks schacki

Comment: do you think you could help show me some generic code for something like that?

Comment: I think the best code example (and from my point of view sufficiently generic) is provided by haineault

Comment: yes you are absolutely right i forgot to clikc that link after reading what you have written, thanks a lot fo the help that was right on

Comment: btw katie: I came across this problem and the solution while working on some recipe application. so if you are interested to share some experience, let me know

Comment: i am interested - right now for some reason the add/remove links are being doubled... i can't figure out where this is occurring but i posted a new question. Maybe you can help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414504/django-dynamic-formset-creating-two-add-remove-links-per-formset) is a link